# Apexcharts crosshair tooltip

Tags: vue.js, apexcharts

I am using Apexcharts with the vue wrapper in my application, There is nothing in the documentation that allows me to edit the tool-tips on the cross-hairs. I would like to edit how it looks as the white box is not working with the design of the page. any help would be much appreciated. thank you

Comment: please provide some code that would help us to figure out the problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS to customize the X-axis tooltip appearance.

```
.apexcharts-xaxistooltip {
  background: #1B213B;
  color: #fff;
}
```

Currently, there is no option to set x-axis tooltip colors in JS. Might be provided in the next releases.

Comment: This works with the vue wrapper as well? I suppose my question would be how do I implement css on the axis object.

Comment: You can write CSS anywhere you want in your Vue application.
Here is an example dashboard which does the same. Notice the CSS panel in the codepen https://codepen.io/apexcharts/pen/pxZKqL